# Integrals of the form $\int_a^b\frac1{F(x)}\sin(\int_a^x F(u) du) dx$, in particular with $F(x)=\sqrt{p_4(x)}h(x)$, for $p_4$ a quartic polynomial

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-integrals

Can we say anything about the integrals of the following type (whether approximately or exact, but not numerically):

$$ I = \int_a^b \frac{1}{F(x)} \sin{\left(\int_a^x F(u) du\right)} dx$$

I am interested in the case when $F(x) = \sqrt{p_4(x)}h(x)$, where $p_4$ is a polynomial of degree 4 with roots $a,b$, and $h(x)$ is an entire complex function. This means the function is holomorphic on an elliptic curve of sorts. Maybe this is doable using the theory of elliptic integrals, but I am  unsure on what to look at.

If you prefer, you can also change $F(x)$ if it allows you to say something about $I$. I am just looking to learn how tackle integrals of this type.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to write it slightly differently for obvious reasons. If we say:
$$I=\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}\sin\left(\int_0^xf(u)du\right)dx$$
where $f(x)=\sqrt{p_4(x)}h(x)$ then we can define $F'(x)=f(x)$ and so:
$$I=\int_a^b\frac{1}{f(x)}\sin\left(F(x)-F(0)\right)dx$$
$$I=\int_a^b\frac{\sin(F(x))\cos(F(0))-\cos(F(x))\sin(F(0))}{f(x)}dx$$
now by letting $u=F(x)\Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{f(x)}=\frac{du}{u'}$ and so we have:
$$I=\int_{F(a)}^{F(b)}\frac{\sin(u)\cos(F(0))-\cos(u)\sin(F(0))}{u'^2}du$$
maybe you can do more with this if you know something about the form of $u'$